# UIViewController title is always (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have this problem. In my initial UIViewController, the title is always null. I have tried `[self setTitile:]` and many other ways of setting title, but nothing works. I suppose there should be the app name as title, and it should be set somewhere in Xcode maybe?
[image]

Here is how I set the title:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Your Title"];
    //[self setTitle:@"Some title"];

. . . 
}
```

I also set title in Storyboard, for the controller and the Nav controller that embeds it, but no luck.
Thank you.

Comment: probably because your `NSString` is `nil`.

Comment: Post the method that sets the title.  It needs to be viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, or viewDidAppear. If you try to set UI elements in your init method, the views aren't loaded yet.

Comment: Is It was a navigation based application?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I guess it is Navigation Based, as I have embedded each view in Nav Controller. I used for example [self setTitle:@"Some Title"]; in viewDidLoad method and also many other options that I found on Stack. Cheers.

Comment: Just try like this [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Your Title"]; instead of [self setTitle:@""];

Comment: Tried that as well before. I remember, in the past after I changed Xcode project name, it did set the title. But then, I had to crete new project, and migrate all the classes to new project, and it changed to null again...

Comment: @MadhuP the `UINavigationController` automatically gets the `title` of the `UIViewController` it is embedding.

Comment: @sermilion please also post the method where you are updating the `title`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below code..

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame];
lbl.text = @"AppName";
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];//18
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.navigationItem.titleView = lbl;
```

//(OR) try

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"AppName";
```

Hope it helps you..!

Comment: Thank you. Your first suggestion works, but the label is not centered.

Comment: Accept it as answer if it is useful to you..
Because of right bar button or text it is causing the label not centered..Check by removing right bar button. It will be center aligned...